# network fails to start at boot time

Tags: networking, arch-linux, systemd

I'm installing arch linux on a new computer, following the arch wiki instructions. But the networks fails to start at boot time;
Here's the output of 'journalctl -xe | grep network' :

> mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd[1]: Starting Wired network...
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd[1]: network.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Wired network.
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd[1]: network.service: Unit entered failed > 
> state.
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd[1]: network.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd-networkd[249]: Enumeration completed
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd-networkd[249]: wlp2s0: Renamed to wlan0
>   mai 03 17:03:11 xxxxx systemd-networkd[249]: wlan0: Renamed to wlp2s0
>   mai 03 17:03:12 xxxxx systemd-networkd[249]: eth0: Renamed to eno1

But if I start the network after the boot 'systemctl start network' then it works.

What looks strange to me is that 'eth0' is renamed to 'eno1' after the network service start, and the network service use 'eno1' for its configuration.

Any idea ?

Comment: Where did you get `network.service` from?

Comment: I just follow the tutorial https://wiki.archlinux.fr/Connexions_reseau chapter "Connexions permanentes" -> "Réseau statique"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion on the arch linux forum it appears that there were an error in the tutorial. The tutorial has been updated and the configuration works now.

[The working solution](https://wiki.archlinux.fr/Connexions_reseau#R.C3.A9seau_statique)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [forums page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=212040), there is a bug in the latest release (1.2.0-3) of the [networkmanager package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/networkmanager/). I reverted to the previous version, which has fixed my issue.